# .NET Implicit conversion of System.Guid to String

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to create an extension method or type converter that will cause this code to compile and run correctly?

```
    Dim x As New System.Guid
    Dim s As String = ctype(x, string)
```

Currently the compiler complains "Value of type 'Guid' cannot be converted to 'String'".

I'm aware I can call x.toString(). However, I have some shared code that tries to generically convert objects to string using CStr(). I was hoping to fold-in a type converter/extension method that would allow that code to work with Guids unchanged.

I believe this would be possible with a custom widening operator if I owned the class in question (guid).

Note: My understanding is CStr() just compiles to CType anyway, thus the use of CType in the example.

Comment: So why not write an extension method that simply calls `x.ToString()`?

Comment: Wouldn't I then need to change the CStr() calls to use this extension method then? The goal is to leave that unchanged.

Comment: Isn't `CStr()` an internal method to VB?

Comment: To define implicit conversion, you have to have control of the class or struct. See this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Unfortunately System.Guid is a struct, and structs don't support inheritance. I don't see an easy solution to provide IMPLICIT conversion. However Robert Harvey is exactly right, there is a very easy EXPLICIT conversion.

Comment: Also you really ought to pick a language. Specifying both c# and vb...not really appropriate.

Comment: If you can, you should modify that shared code to use `ToString`. The only advantage of `CType` is that it handles null references where you'd have to handle that as a special case with `ToString`.